# How to use DateTime string format in a StackPanel?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The AM/PM keeps appearing on the left no matter how I format the DateTime. I've used "G", "hh:mm:ss tt", I've just typed in random numbers followed by "tt" and it always appears on the left when it's in the stackpanel. Outside the stackpanel, it's fine. Any ideas?

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Timestamp, StringFormat=G}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="14"/>

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Sender.FirstName}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="50,0,0,0" FontSize="14"/>

</StackPanel>
```

Output:
PM hh:mm:ss MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: I've found `Binding.StringFormat` to be hilariously useless when it comes to dates. Even if there is an answer, you're probably better off just making an [IValueConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The stringformat worked fine alone, but the stack panel was screwing it up somehow. Specifically the stackpanel with right to left flow direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `StringFormat` with different culture will display different value, IMO better approach will be to use `Converter` and set culture to `InvariantCulture`. I had been facing this situation when I was new to the world of WPF, and this approach has served me well.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Timestamp, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeToStringConverter}}" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="14"/>
```

And you can use converter to use string format of your choice:

```
public class DateTimeToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is DateTime)
            return ((DateTime)value).ToString("G", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using the string converter.

Answer (score 2):

Tested and working.

`TimeStamp` must be `DateTime`.

```
public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

<TextBlock Text="{Binding TimeStamp, StringFormat='{}{0:tt hh:mm:ss MM/dd/yyyy}' }"/>
```